# database value are not show when page refresh

Tags: php

i am building a form in which two combo box 1st combo having more than 6 value and 2 and combo having  only 2 value when user select from combo one choose any value and also select combo 2 1st value and press submit then i open home.php which are fetch value from database and show.
problm-1-
but when i refresh the page value are not print.
problem-2-
next i want when user select from combo1 choose any value and select from combo2 and choose second value then open another page.

```
  <?php 
  session_start();
    ?>
 <html>
 <body>
      <fieldset>


       <select id = "myList" name= "casetype" class="form-login" style="width:250px;" >
           <option value = "D">D</option>
           <option value = "E">E</option>
           <option value = "A">A</option>
           <option value = "C">C</option>
           <option value = "F">F</option>
           <option value = "S">S</option>
           <option value = "B">B</option>
           <option value = "W">W</option>
           <option value = "T">T</option>
           <option value = "R">R</option>
         </select>

    </fieldset>



    </div>
   <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">
   Revision:</div>
  <div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <fieldset>


         <select id = "myList" name="revision" class="form-login" style="width:250px;">
           <option value = "1">R0</option>
           <option value = "2">R1</option>

         </select>
   </fieldset>



           <?php 

         $_SESSION['var']=$_POST['casetype'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); 

      mysql_select_db("Court1") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * from causelist WHERE 
   CaseType= '" . $_SESSION['var'] . "'") 
  or die(mysql_error()); 


    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 

    {

   Print " <td width=15px style=word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;height:40px; >";
     echo $info['CaseNo'];
     print"</td> "; 
    Print " <td style=word-wrap:break-word;text-align:left; width=20px;height:40px;>";
     echo $info['Party2'];
     print"</td> "; 
    Print " <td style=word-wrap:break-word;text-align:left; width=20px;height:40px;>";
     echo $info['Party2'];
     print"</td> ";
      print"</tr> ";
      print"</table> ";
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded? It's not shown in your code and is required when using sessions.

Comment: sir i am using session start but not work

Comment: Where exactly is `session_start();` loaded? Update your question as to where you placed it.

Comment: I don't see `session_start();` in your code yet.

Comment: sorry sir for the mistak....